# Set timeout not working during event listener trigger

Tags: javascript

I have a page where I run a function as soon as the dom is ready at page load. Then I want to trigger it again when a user clicks a link, however for this second time it runs I want it to pause for a few seconds.

I've tried the following and the function runs but the timeout doesn't.

```
function changeRestrictionTime(time) { 
    // DO STUFF
}

require(["dojo/domReady!"], function(){
    changeRestrictionTime('12:00 pm');
    var next7 = document.getElementById('next-7days');
    next7.addEventListener('click', function() {
        setTimeout(changeRestrictionTime('12:00 pm'), 5000);
    }, false);
});
```

Please let me know what the issue is.

Please note - Although I'm using a dojo function for domReady I don't actually know any dojo so prefer to stick with vanilla JS. I don't have access to any other libraries either.
I also don't have access to the markup or AJAX request function

Comment: You don't pass a reference to a function to `setTimeout`, but most likely a `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference:

```
 setTimeout(function() {changeRestrictionTime('12:00 pm')}, 5000);
```

You were executing the function immediately and passing its return value.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I still don't have my head around the concept though, if you can point me in the right direction to learn more I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @dust - It's pretty simple.  If you use `()` after a function name that means to execute it right NOW.  If you use just the function name or an anonymous function with `()`, that's like passing a pointer to the function.  When passing a function as an argument to any other function, you always want just the name.  So, in this case, I created a new anonymous function that could be what was passed and then when it is called, it can call your actual function with the desired parameters.